# orientation of particels in grid mode

Tags: particles

Is it a bug or just logically and i don't understand it?

I have c cube with particles facing perfectly in normal direction. I am happy with that:

[image]

If i change the distribution from random to grid i got this:

[image]

is it a bug? or how can i get normal direction in "grid"-mode?

Comment: Maybe it's a limitation of the grid distribution? There is indeed a bug that makes the orientation and location (=an offset) of the instance object go wrong. You can fix the problem if you check and uncheck the *Use Modifier Stack* checkbox (even when there are no other modifiers). But this doesn't help with the grid distribution. If you want to create a spiky ball you can create an Ico Sphere, use Jittered, uncheck Random Order, and use 1 Particles/Face. Set the number of particles to the number of tris the sphere has.

Comment: Try returning to the first frame of the cache